# Add links to all cells in gridview

Tags: c#, gridview, cells

I have a data source with an unknown number or rows and columns. I am using a grid view which is set to auto generate columns. I need to turn each item in each cell into a link button to post back for processing. I know how to dynamically add a control to a known row and cell but when i don't know the column name it makes it difficult. Any suggestions on how to do produce these results?

Comment: [Stack Overflow is not Your Free Promotional Site™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128560)

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1149071.aspx/1

Comment: Ray i know how to add template and controls when i know the column name. my question is how to add a control to a cell and or every cell with out knowing the column name. how do i iterate through all cells to add a link button to them all?

Comment: If you know the coulmn number, implement the gridview_rowbound function to do the proper formatting to hyperlink. Or is there any info which can determine that coulmn will be hyperlink

Comment: The number of rows and columns can change at any time. I tried the on rowdatabound approach but like you said i need the column number. I don't know how to generically generate the column number on rowdatabound. i need to put all data in all columns into a link button control. its a difficult task i know, i have been at this for a day now.

Comment: If you are changing every cell, is there some reason you cannot simply iterate through `e.Row.Cells` on the `RowDataBound` event? Do you need to exclude any command columns, etc?

Comment: no i dont  need to exclude any columns. I dont know the syntax for iterating through e.row.cells on row data bound. here is my code for changing only on column one row at a time. I would like to change all columns but do know the column name or total number of column.

Comment: <code>
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then

Dim txt As String = e.Row.Cells(2).Text 'get the current text

Dim hl As New HyperLink() 'add new HyperLink to cell instead of text

hl.Text = txt

hl.NavigateUrl = "something.aspx" 'you can use the text of this cell to generate the url

e.Row.Cells(1).Controls.Clear()

e.Row.Cells(1).Controls.Add(hl)

End If</code>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this as a starting point:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
            HyperLink myLink = new HyperLink();
            myLink.NavigateUrl = "somewhere.aspx";
            if (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
            {
                while (cell.Controls.Count > 0)
                {
                    myLink.Controls.Add(cell.Controls[0]);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                myLink.Text = cell.Text;
            }
            cell.Controls.Add(myLink);
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I've written the solution up in C#, as per your tag, but I notice your last comment is in VB. Let me know if you need me to re-post in VB (in which case you should update the tag).

Comment: you rock , that did it. how do i rate you?

Comment: Hit the ^ arrow above the number to the left of the answer to show that this is a good answer, and click the checkmark just below the number and arrows to mark as the accepted answer.